# Parse multiple columns from a dictionary column in python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe consisting of two columns. One column is ID and the other is a nested dictionary of 100+ keys and values.

I'm trying to parse the dictionary column into multiple columns (a column for each key) but I could not figure it out.

What I was able to do is to manually specify each column's name and use the apply function to extract the values from the dictionary:

```
def get_col(row):
    d = ast.literal_eval(row["dictionary_col"])
    js = json.dumps(d["key1"])
    return js


df["key1"]=df.apply(lambda row: get_col(row),axis=1)
```

How can I create a column in `df` for each key in `dictionary_col`?

I found some methods that convert a dictionary to a dataframe but they didn't work since my dictionary is in a column in a dataframe (with the other column being id).

Comment: Obviously not an efficient solution at all, but what I've done for similar situations is make each of those dictionaries into data frames and then concat all of those dataframes together.

Comment: I've been trying to do that but couldn't figure it out. How did you do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can build a new dict from dictionary_col and update df with it:

```
df.update(dictionay_col.to_dict())
```

Comment: dictionay_col.items() throws AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'items'. I've tries df["dictionary_col"] but still didn't work

Comment: That means your dictionary_col is not a dictionary. you need to call to_dict().items() on it: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_dict.html

Comment: Updated my answer to a more concise notation

Comment: I'm getting this error now: ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must must pass an index. I got this error for the other tricks I tried before as well. I think the problem is that there is no ID in the dictionary_col. the ID is in the first column of df. Thoughts?

Comment: Then perhaps I misunderstood. If all you need is to build a dataframe from a Series, you're better off calling df = dictionary_col.to_frame(). Please post a more complete code example if you can with some sample data.